# CreateObject Function is not valid in content. Triggered send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I have a form page with form and this form populates the DE. If it populates the DE, it is redirected to "Thank you" page. On the Thank you page I want to do Trigger send. DE includes fields like : SubscriberKey
EmailAddress    FirstName   LastName    Study_Program_Type  Date_time   ContactId   Program_Duration. and my code in cloudpage :

```
%%[
/* E-posta adresini ve abone anahtarını sorgu dize parametrelerinden al */
SET @email = RequestParameter("Email")
SET @subscriberkey = RequestParameter("Subscriberkey")

/* E-posta adresi ve abone anahtarı ile tetiklenen gönderimi başlat */
SET @tsd_external_key = "Triggered_send"
SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsdef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
SetObjectProperty(@tsdef,"CustomerKey",@tsd_external_key)
SetObjectProperty(@ts,"TriggeredSendDefinition",@tsdef)

/* Yeni bir abone nesnesi oluştur ve e-posta ile abone anahtarını ayarla */
SET @subscriber = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@subscriber,"EmailAddress",@email)
SetObjectProperty(@subscriber,"SubscriberKey",@subscriberkey)

/* Aboneyi tetiklenen gönderiye ekle */
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @subscriber)

Output(InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode))

]%%
```

but I keep getting Error Message: "CreateObject Function is not valid in content. This function is only allowed in non sendable content. Function: CreateObject("TriggeredSend")"

Description: "ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: CreateObject Function is not valid in content. This function is only allowed in non sendable content. Function: CreateObject("TriggeredSend") Error Code: OMM_FUNC_CONTEXT_ERR - from Jint "

where I do mistake?

Comment: I don't find any issues in your code. Just a quick check, did you publish the cloudpage and test it or you previewed the code in the cloudpage? Since the cloudpage preview mode is using the same process as email previews (sendable content context), therefore this error can show up.

Comment: still triggered send is not working, can DE may cause this issue? I have multiple fields inside the DE but I only define subkey and emailaddress in the code.

Comment: How and where do you see this error? Like you submit the form then it redirects to the thank you page and the thank you page showed the error "CreateObject Function is not valid in content...?